# How to properly configure route to show only subdirectories?

Tags: flask

I am unable to download a csv from sub-directory but I can do it from a home directory.

I've tried changing routes to the subdirectory, but it throws 404 error.

```py
@app.route('/', defaults={'req_path': 'Categorized%20Output/2019-06-27'})
@app.route('/<path:req_path>')
def index(req_path):
    # data = dataset.html
    #return dataset.html
    folderLocation = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    print(folderLocation)
    abs_path = os.path.join(folderLocation,req_path)
    print(abs_path)
    # Return 404 if path doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(abs_path):
        return abort(404)

    # Check if path is a file and serve
    if os.path.isfile(abs_path):
        return send_file(abs_path)

    # Show directory contents
    files = os.listdir(abs_path)
    return render_template('index.html',files = files)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My CSV's are located in multiple subfolder named as different dates in FolderLocation/Categorized Output/*lot's of dates folder*/

The index.html file from templates

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}"/>
  <title>Show CSV</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <ul>
    {% for file in files %}
    <li><a href="{{ file }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to download CSV's from all different dates subfolder.
An example of the location of CSV's is: "127.0.0.1:5000/Categorized%20Output/2019-06-27"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a convenient way to grab a file/directory recently by using easygui.

```
pip install easygui
```

```py
import easygui

@app.route('/')
def index():
    get_a_file = easygui.fileopenbox()
    files = get_a_file # do some stuff with your file
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)
```

This answer doesn't address the root of your issue, but if it helps and you're interested you can read the [easygui documentation](https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

if you want to start with a specific directory you can customize fileopenbox such as..

```
files = easygui.fileopenbox(
                    msg='some message',
                    title='some title', 
                    default='c:\some_directory\some_directory\*.file_type',
                    filetype='*.file_type'
                    )
```

where file_type is any type of file.. .txt, .dat, etc.,

Comment: This almost solves the problem but I don't want anyone to see any other directories except the Categorized output.

Comment: i've included an edit to show an example of how to start at a specific directory. is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: you might want to look into os.walk     https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk